# pivot pandas dataframe to generate several columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot, pandas-groupby

The dataframe I have now looks like this:

```
        nut_no   g            grams            label(g)         label(grams)
0       0.0      150          150 No units     Calories(kcal)   Calories        
1       1.0      2g(3% DV)    2 grams(3% DV)   Total Fat(g)     Total Fat(grams)    
2       2.0      30g(10% DV)  30 grams(10% DV) Total Carbs(g)   Total Carbs(grams)
3       3.0      4g           4 grams          Protein(g)       Protein(grams)
4       0.0      300          300 No units     Calories(kcal)   Calories
5       1.0      12g(18% DV)  12 grams(18% DV) Total Fat(g)     Total Fat(grams)
6       2.0      30g(10% DV)  30 grams(10% DV) Total Carbs(g)   Total Carbs(grams)
7       3.0      18g          18 grams         Protein(g)       Protein(grams)
```

Below is the dataframe output I would like generate :

```
    Calories(kcal) Calories     Total Fat(g)  Total Fat(grams)  Total Carbs(g) Total Carbs(grams)  Protein(g)    Protein(grams)    
1   150            150 No units 2g(3% DV)     2 grams(3% DV)    30g(10% DV)  30 grams(10% DV)      4g            4 grams
2   300            300 No units 12g(18% DV)   12 grams(18% DV)  30g(10% DV)  30 grams(10% DV)      18g           18 grams
```

4 sequential rows (column "nut_no" and values 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0) from the starting dataframe are combined to form one row in the output dataframe. The values in the "label(g)" and "label(grams)" columns become the column headers for the values in the "g" and "grams" columns.  I also need to maintain the order, that is the first 4 rows must become row 1 in the output, the next 4 rows must become row 2, etc.

I have tried several different things with pivot and groupby but I am just not finding my way, so help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use dual pivot and concat for this i.e

```
one = df.pivot(values='g',columns='label(g)').apply(lambda x : sorted(x,key=pd.isnull)).dropna()

two = df.pivot(values='grams',columns='label(grams)').apply(lambda x : sorted(x,key=pd.isnull)).dropna()

ndf = pd.concat([one,two],1)
```

Output :

```
 Calories(kcal) Protein(g) Total Carbs(g) Total Fat(g)      Calories  \
0            150         4g    30g(10% DV)    2g(3% DV)  150 No units   
1            300        18g    30g(10% DV)  12g(18% DV)  300 No units   

  Protein (grams) Total Carbs(grams)  Total Fat(grams)  
0         4 grams   30 grams(10% DV)    2 grams(3% DV)  
1        18 grams   30 grams(10% DV)  12 grams(18% DV)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the input but I dont really see how this gets me closer to my end goal of having one row, which represents the combination of first 4 rows, and has the columns of Calories(kcals), Calories, Total Fat(g), Total Fat(grams), Total Carbs(g), Total Carbs(grams), Protein(g), and Protein(grams)

Comment: Oh my god. So sorry. I reversed the order. I misunderstood the input and output. They are interchanged sorry give me  a sec

Comment: not a problem, I just thought I was supposed to infer how to get to my needed result from your reshaping ...and I couldnt see it....

Comment: Can you put input first and output second in your question. I misunderstood and wasted my time.

Comment: edited question to reverse input and output...sorry you wasted your time

Comment: I updated my answer. Do not the space between `protein (grams)` in your dataset. Present for one and absent for other.

Comment: @Wen he had put output first and input second . I misunderstood and posted a different solution. So told to reverse the order.

Comment: @Wen are you trying  a crosstab solution?

Comment: @Bharath pivot and crosstab almost the same no need to keep both :-)

Comment: So any improvement you suggest ?